# How can I reference a specific point of my function inside NDSolve?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations, equation-solving

### The problem:

I am trying to solve this diffrential equation:

```
K[x_, x1_] := 1;
NDSolve[{A''[x] == Integrate[K[x, x1] A[x1], {x1, 0, 1}], 
         A[0] == 0, A'[1] == 1}, A[x], x]
```

and I'm getting errors (`Function::slotn` and `NDSolve::ndnum`)
(it should return a numeric function that is equal to `3/16 x^2 + 5/8 x`)

I am looking for a way to solve this differential equation: Is there a way to write it in a better form, such that NDSolve will understand it? Is there another function or package that can help?

**Note 1:** In my full problem, `K[x, x1]` is not 1 -- it depends (in a complex way) on `x` and `x1`.
**Note 2:** Naively deriving the two sides of the equation with respect to `x` won't work, because the integral limits are definite.

### My first impression:

It seems that *Mathematica* doesn't like me referencing a point in `A[x]` -- the same errors occur when I'm doing this simplified version:

```
NDSolve[{A''[x] == A[0.5], A[0] == 0, A'[1] == 1}, A[x], x]
```

(it should return a numeric function that is equal to `2/11 x^2 + 7/11 x`)

In this case one can avoid this problem by analytically solving `A''[x] == c`, and then finding `c`, but in my first problem it seems to not work -- it only transform the differential equation to an integral one, which (N)DSolve doesn't solve afterwards.

Comment: Your equation is an integro-differential, not just differential. I don't think `NDSolve` ever claimed to be able to solve integro - differential equations. So, unless you manage to reduce it to a differential equation (get rid of the integral), it looks like you are out of luck. Another possibility would be to integrate twice over `x` (since you will need to only integrate the kernel `K`) - if this is possible (convergence etc), you will end up with the integral equation and can attempt to solve that. Such integration will introduce 2 arbitrary constants which you fix with initial conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Several points:
1 - I know that `NDSolve` have problems with i.d. equations. I was hoping to find a diffrent syntex, or a different function/package, or any other solution for it.

Comment: 2 - Is there a way to solve the second example, without using the `c`? It seems to me like a simpler example, and I included it specifically because it doesn't have an integral.

Comment: 3 - I can indeed get an equivalent integral equation - but I don't know any _Mathematica_ Function that solves such equations. Do you know such one? (I'm currently bypassing and solving with `FixedPoint`, but I'm still limited with it)

Comment: You seem to expect that NDSolve returns a symbolic solution to the differential equation (you name the expected functions twice). AFAIK NDSolve returns an InterpolatingFunction object. For symbolic solutions you should use DSolve instead.

Comment: I'm aware that `NDSolve` return an `InterpolationFunction`. I named the expected results to assist potential helpers who want to check their approach. I'll make it more clear in the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can suggest a way to reduce your equation to an integral equation, which can be solved numerically by approximating its kernel with a matrix, thereby reducing the integration to matrix multiplication.

First, it is clear that the equation can be integrated twice over `x`, first from `1` to `x`, and then from `0` to `x`, so that:

[image]

We can now discretize this equation, putting it on a equidistant grid:

[image]

Here, the `A[x]` becomes a vector, and the integrated kernel `iniIntK` becomes a matrix, while integration is replaced by a matrix multiplication. The problem is then reduced to a system of linear equations.

The easiest case (that I will consider here) is when the kernel `iniIntK` can be derived analytically - in this case this method will be quite fast. Here is the function to produce the integrated kernel as a pure function:

```
Clear[computeDoubleIntK]
computeDoubleIntK[kernelF_] :=
  Block[{x, x1},
   Function[
    Evaluate[
      Integrate[
         Integrate[kernelF[y, x1], {y, 1, x}] /. x -> y, {y, 0, x}] /. 
         {x -> #1, x1 -> #2}]]];
```

In our case:

```
In[99]:= K[x_,x1_]:=1;

In[100]:= kernel = computeDoubleIntK[K]
Out[100]= -#1+#1^2/2&
```

Here is the function to produce the kernel matrix and the r.h,s vector:

```
 computeDiscreteKernelMatrixAndRHS[intkernel_, a0_, aprime1_ , 
    delta_, interval : {_, _}] :=
  Module[{grid, rhs, matrix},
    grid = Range[Sequence @@ interval, delta];
    rhs = a0 + aprime1*grid; (* constant plus a linear term *)
    matrix = 
      IdentityMatrix[Length[grid]] - delta*Outer[intkernel, grid, grid];
    {matrix, rhs}]
```

To give a very rough idea how this may look like (I use here `delta = 1/2`):

```
In[101]:= computeDiscreteKernelMatrixAndRHS[kernel,0,1,1/2,{0,1}]

Out[101]= {{{1,0,0},{3/16,19/16,3/16},{1/4,1/4,5/4}},{0,1/2,1}}
```

We now need to solve the linear equation, and interpolate the result, which is done by the following function:

```
Clear[computeSolution];
computeSolution[intkernel_, a0_, aprime1_ , delta_, interval : {_, _}] :=
With[{grid = Range[Sequence @@ interval, delta]},
  Interpolation@Transpose[{
    grid,
    LinearSolve @@ 
      computeDiscreteKernelMatrixAndRHS[intkernel, a0, aprime1, delta,interval]
  }]]
```

Here I will call it with a `delta = 0.1`:

```
In[90]:= solA = computeSolution[kernel,0,1,0.1,{0,1}]
Out[90]= InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>]
```

We now plot the result vs. the exact analytical solution found by @Sasha, as well as the error:

[image]

I intentionally chose `delta` large enough so the errors are visible. If you chose `delta` say `0.01`, the plots will be visually identical. Of course, the price of taking smaller `delta` is the need to produce and solve larger matrices.

For kernels that can be obtained analytically, the main bottleneck will be in the `LinearSolve`, but in practice it is pretty fast (for matrices not too large). When kernels can not be integrated analytically, the main bottleneck will be in computing the kernel in many points (matrix creation. The matrix inverse has a larger asymptotic complexity, but this will start play a role for really large matrices - which are not necessary in this approach, since it can be combined with an iterative one - see below). You will typically define:

```
intK[x_?NumericQ, x1_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[K[y, x1], {y, 1, x}]
intIntK[x_?NumericQ, x1_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[intK[z, x1], {z, 0, x}]
```

As a way to speed it up in such cases, you can precompute the kernel `intK` on a grid and then interpolate, and the same for `intIntK`. This will however introduce additional errors, which you'll have to estimate (account for).

The grid itself needs not be equidistant (I just used it for simplicity), but may (and probably should) be adaptive, and generally non-uniform.

As a final illustration, consider an equation with a non-trivial but symbolically integrable kernel:

```
In[146]:= sinkern =  computeDoubleIntK[50*Sin[Pi/2*(#1-#2)]&]

Out[146]= (100 (2 Sin[1/2 \[Pi] (-#1+#2)]+Sin[(\[Pi] #2)/2] 
     (-2+\[Pi] #1)))/\[Pi]^2&

In[157]:= solSin = computeSolution[sinkern,0,1,0.01,{0,1}]
Out[157]= InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>]
```

[image]

Here are some checks:

```
In[163]:= Chop[{solSin[0],solSin'[1]}]
Out[163]= {0,1.}

In[153]:= 
diff[x_?NumericQ]:=
  solSin''[x] - NIntegrate[50*Sin[Pi/2*(#1-#2)]&[x,x1]*solSin[x1],{x1,0,1}];

In[162]:= diff/@Range[0,1,0.1]

Out[162]=  {-0.0675775,-0.0654974,-0.0632056,-0.0593575,-0.0540479,-0.0474074,
   -0.0395995,-0.0308166,-0.0212749,-0.0112093,0.000369261}
```

To conclude, I just want to stress that one has to perform a careful error - estimation analysis for this method, which I did not do.

**EDIT**

You can also use this method to get the initial approximate solution, and then iteratively improve it using `FixedPoint` or other means - in this way you will have a relatively fast convergence and will be able to reach the required precision without the need to construct and solve huge matrices.

Comment: Holy Cow! this is a lot of excellent work. I've used already a method with `FixedPoint` on the integral equation, and this seems like an awesome addition to my arsenal.

Comment: Ended up using a combination of this method and of: `f[A_] := FunctionInterpolation[x - Integrate[Integrate[Integrate[K[x2, x3] A[x3], {x3, 0, 1}], {x2, x1, 1}], {x1, 0, x}], {x, 0, 1}]; 
percision = 0.003; maxiterations = 100000; 
sol = FixedPoint[f, FunctionInterpolation[z, {z, 0, 1}], maxiterations, SameTest -> (N[Integrate[(#1[x] - #2[x])^2, {x, 0, 1}]] < percision N[Integrate[(#1[x])^2, {x, 0, 1}]] &)]`. thanks for your useful code!

Comment: @j0ker5 Thanks for the accept. I am happy it worked for you. It's a shame I was the only one to think that the question deserves a vote.

Answer (score 4):

This is complementary to Leonid Shifrin's approach. We start with a linear function that interpolates the value and first derivative at the starting point. We use that in the integration with the given kernel function. We can then iterate, using each previous approximation in the integrated kernel that is used to make the next approximation.

I show an example below, using a more complicated kernel than just a constant function. I'll take it through two iterations and show tables of discrepancies.

```
kernel[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x]/(y^2 + 1/5)*Sin[x^2 + y]
intkern[x_?NumericQ, aa_] := 
 NIntegrate[kernel[x, y]*aa[y], {y, 0, 1}, MinRecursion -> 2, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 3]

Clear[a];
a0 = 0;
a1 = 1;
a[0][x_] := a0 + a1*x

soln1 = a[1][x] /. 
   First[NDSolve[{(a[1]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == intkern[x, a[0], y], 
      a[1][0] == a0, a[1][1] == a1}, a[1][x], {x, 0, 1}]];
a[1][x_] = soln1;

In[283]:= Table[a[1]''[x] - intkern[x, a[1]], {x, 0., 1, .1}]

Out[283]= {4.336808689942018*10^-19, 0.01145100326794241, \
0.01721655945379122, 0.02313249302884235, 0.02990900241909161, \
0.03778448183557359, 0.04676409320217928, 0.05657128568058478, \
0.06665818935524814, 0.07624149919589895, 0.08412643746245929}

In[285]:= 
soln2 = a[2][x] /. 
   First[NDSolve[{(a[2]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == intkern[x, a[1]], 
      a[2][0] == a0, a[2][1] == a1}, a[2][x], {x, 0, 1}]];
a[2][x_] = soln2;

In[287]:= Table[a[2]''[x] - intkern[x, a[2]], {x, 0., 1, .1}]

Out[287]= {-2.168404344971009*10^-19, -0.001009606971360516, \
-0.00152476679745811, -0.002045817184941901, -0.002645356229312557, \
-0.003343218015068372, -0.004121109614310836, -0.004977453722712966, \
-0.005846840469889258, -0.006731367269472544, -0.007404971586975062}
```

So we have errors of less than .01 at this stage. Not too bad. One drawback is that it was fairly slow to get the second approximation. There may be ways to tune NDSolve to improve on that.

This is complementary to Leonid's method for two reasons.

(1) If this did not converge well because the initial linear approximation was not sufficiently close to the true result, one might instead begin with an approximation found by a finite differencing scheme. That would be akin to what he did.

(2) He pretty much indicated this himself, as a method that might follow his and produce refinements.

Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: Nice! Indeed, perfectly complements my suggestion - just what I meant in my edit. +1

Answer (score 0):

The way your equation is currently written `A''[x] == const`, and than constant is independent of `x`. Hence the solution always has the form of quadratic polynomial. Your problem then reduces to a solving for indeterminate coefficients:

```
In[13]:= A[x_] := a2 x^2 + a1 x + a0;

In[14]:= K[x_, x1_] := 1;

In[16]:= Solve[{A''[x] == Integrate[K[x, x1] A[x1], {x1, 0, 1}], 
  A[0] == 0, A'[1] == 1}, {a2, a1, a0}]

Out[16]= {{a2 -> 3/16, a1 -> 5/8, a0 -> 0}}

In[17]:= A[x] /. First[%]

Out[17]= (5 x)/8 + (3 x^2)/16
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with that is that `A''[x] == const` only when `K` does not depend on `x` and `x1`. Unfortunately, this is only true for the simplified example. (but I will try to see if any similar approach can be valid in my case)